# Why are there multiple envoy service in opentelemetry example?

Tags: open-telemetry, envoyproxy

[Envoy official opentelemetry exaple](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/sandboxes/opentelemetry)

Just wondering why are there 3 envoy to map to 2 service

- envoy-front-proxy
- envoy-1
- envoy-2

```
service path
/trace/1 (envoy-front-proxy) ---> envoy-1 ---> service-1
/trace/2 (envoy-front-proxy) ---> envoy-1 ---> envoy-2 ---> service-2
```

Why not just 1 envoy to map to 2 service?

```
service path
/trace/1 (envoy-front-proxy) ---> service-1
/trace/2 (envoy-front-proxy) ---> service-2
```